# Узнать файл передаваемый в параметрах командной строки

Tags: c#, xml, config

Мне надо чтобы бы я мог в параметрах командной строки при запуске программы, указать, какой именно файл я хочу разбирать. и только если этот файл не указан, тогда разбирать файл "по умолчанию" - рядом лежащий файл

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  if (args.Length == 0) 
  {
    var dirPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    Раобрать_Файл(dirPath + "По_Умолчанию.txt");
  }
  else
    foreach(string filename in args)
      Раобрать_Файл(filename);
}
```